# kernel of irreducible characters

Tags: characters, gap

I want to use GAP to check some property of a group. I am wondering if there is an easy way (several commands) to find the kernel of each irreducible representations.

Comment: Are your irreps already constructed each as some sort of explicit group homomorphism? Does the built in command `Kernel()` not work?

Comment: I only know how to calculate character table, I am not familiar how to use it.

Comment: Have you looked in the manual? Is there maybe a chance that the function `KernelOfCharacter` does what you want.

Comment: @ahulpke for character tables like CharacterTable("4_1.L3(4).2_3")  that do not store the underlying group is there an easy way to calculate the size of the kernel of the character?

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira.  You can use `Sum(SizesConjugacyClasses(tbl){ClassPositionsOfKernel(char)});`